# VBA - setting a date format to a variable

Tags: vba, date, variables, format

Novice `VBA` user here. I think this might be a very easy question to answer, but I cant find the solution on here on any other site so apologies if that's the case.

I am writing a very short piece of code that inserts the latest business day into a column where its not already present and moves onto the next column and runs the same process where it is present. The code is below. Note I have simplified this by but removing the else condition. I want to set the date format for the `lastbusinessday` variable to be `"dd/mm/yyyy"` - at the moment its including `hh/mm/ss` which is causing the if function to not work properly.

How can i declare the conditions for this variable?

```
Sub Dateextend4()
    Dim lastbusinessday As Date

    If Weekday(Now()) = 2 Then
        lastbusinessday = (Now() - 3)
    Else
        lastbusinessday = (Now() - 1)
    End If

    Sheets("pb CDS").Select
    Range("b13").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select

    If ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Value < lastbusinessday Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0) = format(lastbusinessday, "mm / dd / yyyy")
    Else
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Try just using `date()`?

Comment: Sorry I am not sure what you mean. Where do I use 'date()' and do I put the format I want "dd/mm/yyyy" inside the brackets?

Comment: Replace `Now()` with `Date()` and also using capital MM for month

Comment: That works. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your problem (the tick next the the answer).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
If Weekday(Date()) = 2 Then
    lastbusinessday = (Date() - 3)
Else
    lastbusinessday = (Date() - 1)
End If

Format(lastbusinessday, "dd/MM/yyyy")
```